# Inherent vs Intrinsic

Tags: word-usage, differences, synonyms

Random House has

> inherent: existing in something as a permanent and inseparable element.
>
> intrinsic: belonging to the thing by its very nature.

Are these the same? Are they interchangeable?

I was debating with myself as to the proper usage in:

> They debated the inherent dangers of materialism.

Would this be better?

> They debated the dangers intrinsic in materialism.

Comment: Funny that, I'd say 'inherent in' and 'intrinsic to' . Is one of us wrong, are we both right, or is it British and American usage again, like 'different from' and  'different than'?

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to go against @Edward Stirling's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As an American, I like the first option better, though I would phrase it:

> They debated the dangers inherent in materialism.

I think the connection of dangers to the the very *nature* of materialism is trivial here and that this word expresses a bit too much. But inherent certainly sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

i think "inherent **to**" is more correct than "inherent **in**". But "inherent property **of**" is also correct. "Inherent" is more for describing properties drawn out of something, as logical derivatives of its nature.  Think of the word "inherit".  Intrinsic means the property is within the thing, like the intrinsic value of a cooking pot being that you can cook with it, as opposed to the extrinsic value that the law of supply and demand would grant it.
I think inherent is more appropriate for your example since "danger" is not an explicit or implicit part of materialism, but is more of an inevitable property that is only apparent after drawing it out logically.